# Making confidence interval function in R.

Tags: statistics, programming

I want to make confidence interval function in R
I'm trying to make following this one(Ration confidence interval function).

```
p.conf=function(x,n,alpha){
  phat=x/n
  z=qnorm(1-alpha/2)
  ss=sqrt(phat*(1-phat)/n)
  if(n*phat>=15 & n*(1-phat)>=15)
  phat+c(-z*ss,z*ss) else print ("z cannot")                                                          
}
```

But I can't get how to make one when I know about specimen of Population.
I want to have similar form with those code I uploaded.
Please help me.

Comment: What does "I know about specimen of Population" mean?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:coding-theory]? Do you read the tag wikis at all, or are you just adding tags at random? In math common words often have a technical meaning, so if you don't know for sure, then you are very likely to go wrong.

Comment: Sorry for using inadequate words. I mean 'sample of population' for 'specimen for population'. Really sorry. And I also delete tag 'coding-theory'.Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is a sample of size $n$ from a normal population, then
a confidence interval for the population mean $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm t^* s/\sqrt{n}.$

In R, $\bar X$ can be found as `a = mean(x)` where `x` is an $n$-vector of data,
$s$ can be found as `s = sd(x)` and $t^*$ as `t.star = qt(1 - alpha/2, n-1)`,
where the confidence level is $1 - \alpha/2.$ For example, a 95% confidence
interval would use $\alpha = .05.$  The function `qt` is the quantile
function of Student's t distribution. I will leave it to you to combine
everything into a function (perhaps using `pm = c(-1,1)` for $\pm$).

BTW: The binomial confidence interval you are using is not the best.
The 'plus-4' or 'Agresti' confidence interval is now generally recognized as more accurate.
If there are $X$ successes in $n$ trials, it is of the form
$$\tilde p \pm z^*\sqrt{\tilde p(1-\tilde p)/\tilde n},$$
where $\tilde n = n + 4$ and $\tilde p = (X+2)/\tilde n.$

This formula is best for 95% confidence intervals. Even more accurate
is the (more intricate) Wilson confidence interval. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).